# how to update data in subcontroller in ios, swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, reloaddata

I have `viewcontroller` and it has split by two views. one is view which cotrolled by `tableviewcontroller` which is `childcontroller` of `viewcontroller`, and one is `statusview` which is show data directly when tableviewcontroller`s`didselectrowatindexpath`is called. but when i can`t reload my data in statusview when i called `didselectrowatindexpath`. i can relaod my data in `tableview` but status view does not reflect data.
[image]

the darkgray area is statusview and middle view is `tableview`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

by this code i can reload my data in `tableview` . but when i use `setneedsDisplay` or `setneedslayout` of parentController(viewcontroller) it crash. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What do you want the data to be in the status bar?

Comment: If you want to update the `statusView` with some data that is related to the selected row of tableview you can access the `statusView` by `(self.parent as? ParentViewController)?.statusView` and update it in `tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: i want to show number in each cell in statusview!!

Comment: hardik parmar hey!! it did work but statusView does not change

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will need one of these two options:

1. Create a protocol that your main `UIViewController` will implement, so that `UITableViewController` can pass data via the delegate to its parent view controller
2. Post a UINotification in the `UITableViewController` and receive this notification in your status bar view and display the data.

Lets explore both options:

Define a protocol, in this example I am only sending a `String` of the cell that was tapped on:

```
@objc protocol YourDataProtocol {
    func didSelectCell(withString string: String)
}
```

Next add a delegate property to your `UITableViewController`

```
class YourTableViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: YourDataProtocol?
...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        //call the delegate method with your text - in this case just text from textLabel
        if let text = cell?.textLabel?.text {
            delegate?.didSelectCell(withString: text)
        }
    }    
}
```

Make your `UIViewContoller` be the delegate of the `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, YourDataProtocol {
    ...
    let yourTableVC = YourTableViewController(...
    yourTableVC.delegate = self 

    func didSelectCell(withString string: String) {
        statusBar.text = string//update the status bar
    }
}
```

Second option is with using `NotificationCenter`

In your `UITableViewController` you post a notification

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if let text = cell?.textLabel?.text {
        let notificatioName = Notification.Name("DataFromTableViewCell")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificatioName, object: nil, userInfo: ["YourData": text])
    }
}
```

In status bar you start listening to this notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didReceiveData(_:)), name: notificatioName, object: nil)

@objc func didReceiveData(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let userData = notification.userInfo, let stringFromCell = userData["YourData"] {
        print(stringFromCell)
    }
}
```